# change table alternative rows colors using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change colors for alternative rows. one row in "Green" and another one is in "Yellow".

```
<tr class="ms-viewheader" vAlign="top">
<tr class="">
<tr class="ms-alternating">
<tr class="">
<tr class="ms-alternating">
<tr class="">
<tr class="ms-alternating">
<tr class="">
<tr class="ms-alternating">
```

I have to skip "ms-viewheader" row and start coloring next sibling. Full row should be in 
color.

How to do this?

Comment: Not sure about this: Give all of them the same class, and loop through $('tr.sameclass') and give them style one time green and one time yellow

Comment: I can not give same. It is out of the box feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of the box feature"?

Comment: @OmerPT: it is sharepoint list. trying to change colors in the list.

Comment: Is `ms-alternating` already there or do  you need to add it?

Comment: @ melhosseiny :The code that gave already there. I need to jquery code and add color

Comment: If the `ms-alternating` classes are already there in the markup for you, you shouldn't need any jquery to do what you are asking. Please see answer i just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want to just handle this one table. Try this:

```
$("table[class='ms-listviewtable'] tr[class='']").css("background-color","yellow");
$("table[class='ms-listviewtable'] tr:.ms-alternating").css("background-color","green")
```

I am assuming that the table has a class, otherwise you could add a class to it to differentiate it.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/J7dVX/13/

Answer (score 4):

run something like this in javascript

```
// define the background color for even and odd rows
var bgColors = {
  even: '#eaeaea',
  odd:  '#aeaeae'
};
$("table tr:not(.ms-viewheader):even").css({"backgroundColor":bgColors.even});
$("table tr:not(.ms-viewheader):odd").css({"backgroundColor":bgColors.odd});
```

Comment: Where are you applying colors for alternative rows?

Comment: I am adding the CSS class 'ms-alternating' to every other row.  You would need to have a CSS class for 'ms-alternating' that specifies background color, etc.

Comment: I already have that css "ms-alternating" in the code. This sharepoint list Out of the box list. I need to write jQuery code to add colors. thats it

Comment: I think Teddy is saying you need to add some additional CSS. You don't need to change the original CSS. You should be able to add some of your own on top of it to override.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to use JS? Here's a CSS solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/HvLRs/1/

CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(2n) {  
   background-color:green;
} 
tr:nth-child(4n) {  
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="alternating">
    <th class="ms-viewheader" vAlign="top"><td>Header</td></th>
    <tr class=""><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class=""><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating"><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr class=""><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating"><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr class=""><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating"><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you must use jQuery, I modified Teddy's code: http://jsfiddle.net/HvLRs/3/

```
$("table tr:.ms-alternating:even").css("background-color","yellow");
$("table tr:.ms-alternating:odd").css("background-color","green");
```

Comment: I don't see any coloring for   <tr class=""><td>1</td></tr>

Comment: Huh? The first link doesn't set an inline style. It uses css. The second link should set an inline style though. What browser are you using?

Comment: I like this answer. This should be entirely possible to do in CSS and not require any javascript. (However, I think the OP would want `2n` and `2n+1`, not 2n and 4n.) Of course, as much as I like saying "please do this in CSS, not javascript", the problem is that poor old IE8 won't support this, so probably using javascript is more appealing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it dynamically, use:

```
$("tr[class='']").css("background-color", "green");
$(".ms-alternating").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

As an alternative you could also use:

```
$(".ms-viewheader").siblings().css("background-color", "green");
$(".ms-alternating").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: What about <tr class="">  coloring?

Comment: come on.. this will messup whole page where ever tr is. I have to <th class="ms-viewheader"> then move to next sibling for coloring <tr>. your $("tr").css("background-color", "blue"); apply color to all <tr>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat `ms-viewheader` the same as `ms-alternating`:

```
$('tr:not([class^="ms"])').css('background-color','red');
$('tr[class^="ms"]').css('background-color','blue');
```

otherwise, if you just want to skip `ms-viewheader` and start alternating all the other rows:

```
$('tr:not([class^="ms"])').css('background-color','red');
$('tr.ms-alternating').css('background-color','blue');
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/daybreaker/J7dVX/

Comment: [class^="ms"] are in other place in the page. So it is apply all the places.

Comment: James: So use a limiter in your selector. Does the table have a class or an ID?  $('table#thatoneannoyingtable tr:not([class^="ms"])') etc. etc...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - use modulus

```
for row, i in $('tbody tr')
  color = if i % 2 is 0 then '#ff0000' else '#00ff00'
  $(row).css 'background-color', color
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your latest comment on the original question that the `ms-alternating` class is already there in the markup for you??

If so, you shouldn't need any jquery or fancy CSS3 rules to do this. You can do this with regular ol' CSS.

Just add this to your CSS:

```
tr td {
    background-color:green; /* this colors the whole table green */
}
tr.ms-viewheader td {
    background-color:transparent; /* we don't want the header to get any color, so reset it */
}
tr.ms-alternating td {
    background-color:yellow; /* and finally, color the alternating rows yellow */
}
```

Please note, this will color all tables on the page. You probably only want to target a single table. So you need some more specific selectors. Does the table you want to color have an ID or class on it you could target?

Good luck!